# How to aggregate logs and metrics from multiple modules accross different servers?

Tags: monitoring, java

We are thinking about setting up a solution for aggregating logs and metrics from multiple modules accross different servers. The problem is that it needs to run in a hospital and the logs may contain patient data when we debug a problem. So all external solutions are not possible. Also it needs to run as a windows service, as hospitals here usually only use Windows.

The modules are a normal Spring Boot application. The modules can connect to central server but not the other way around, so it needs to push the data to a central server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking into using [Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana), [Loki, and Promtail](https://github.com/grafana/loki) on-premises. Because they are implemented in Go, cross-compiling to run in Windows is possible. For the past several years, I have been extremely pleased using Grafana in private, on-prem settings disconnected from external world.

Additionally, consider time series database systems for metrics. In your case, [InfluxDB](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb) might be a more suitable choice than [Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus) because of push vs pull models.

Check out shared [dashboards](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/?pg=docs-grafana-latest-dashboards) you can download and install.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know Loki. The setup seems feasible.